# DrawerLayout Not Scrolling

Tags: android

I notice that the drawers within the Google applications are scrollable, but I cannot for some reason come to the conclusion of how to achieve a scrollable DrawerLayout.  I attempted to construct the layout file with the following design paradigm.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".mainScreen">
    <!-- Layout of Activity -->
  </FrameLayout>

  <!-- DrawerLayout segment -->
  <ScrollView
     android:id="@+id/scrollView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/drawerLinearLayout"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="260dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
      android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
      android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
      android:dividerHeight="0dp"
      android:background="#77000000">
     <!-- Layout of Drawer -->
     </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But, with or without the ScrollView, the drawer just cuts items off at the bottom when they go beyond the end of the screen.  I can't get any form of scrolling enabled.  Not sure what I am missing or need to enable.  Thoughts would be appreciated.

The LinearLayout in the DrawerLayout segment contains different styled views.  One view displays title only with a divider below it, one displays an imageview with text next to it and another displays a title with a switch built into the row.  So, multiple styled views need to be accounted for if done outside of XML coded layout files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While using a ListView is a valid option, it was useful for me to attempt and resolve the situation for which I already had such a large XML file constructed for my layout in between the ScrollView above.  As it turned out, there were only a few small modifications needed in order to get it working as intended.  The latest layout file constructed is the following:

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".mainScreen">
    <!-- Layout of Activity -->
  </FrameLayout>

  <!-- DrawerLayout segment -->
  <ScrollView
     android:id="@+id/scrollView"
     android:layout_width="260dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
     android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
     <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/drawerLinearLayout"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="260dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
      android:dividerHeight="0dp"
      android:background="#77000000">
     <!-- Layout of Drawer -->
     </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The main modifications required me to alter where the gravity and the margin existed.  The gravity needed to be in the surrounding ScrollView otherwise it would cause odd behavior that didn't scroll or actually crashed in some instances apparently.  Then the inner layout needed to be changed to 'wrap content'.

If the margin was not moved into the ScrollView as well, it apparently doesn't scroll down to the bottom.  It left a margin of scroll unscrolled at the bottom.  Once this was resolved, the DrawerLayout worked as was expected at this point.  The ListView option also proposed is another approach to be used, but as mentioned at this point it was worth me analyzing it a bit further to re-use the code that I already had written; especially with several different custom views that would need to be handled inside the view.

Comment: I tried using this but my mDrawerItems doesn't display anymore. Is the problem still on the layout?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it only works properly with a ListView. You will take less time to migrate to ListView than trying to make the ScrollView to work.

Comment: No, it worked out just fine as mentioned above with a ScrollView with just a simple fix.  However, the other approach is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a listview along with the frame layout. Something like this :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You can also refer to the Navigation Drawer documentation at developer.android.com. It has everything you will need.

Comment: The DrawerLayout is not designed to be scrollable by default (or via a small configuration change) as I understand your response. I would be forced to redesign the entire layout that was created to work inside of a ListView instead of inside the XML.  Is that correct?

Comment: Are you using some custom layout for your items in drawer ? If yes then you will have to use that layout in a custom adapter for list view. ListView will handle scrolling and manage items easily which will be difficult if done manually.

Comment: No, the following below was the solution, however your approach as well would have probably gotten the job done.  And I appreciate your response.  I'll be considering ListView constructed layouts now in future going forward with other projects.